# Using Microsoft Word Plug-in/VSTO to intercept Drag/Drop Events

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, drag-and-drop, vsto

**Problem:** I'm writing a Word 2013 Add-in/Plug-in/VSTO and need to intercept the drag/drop events from/to the instance of Word where my plug-in is running.

**Solution:** I'm attempting to use the [RegisterDragDrop function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678405(v=vs.85).aspx) with an implementation of [IDropTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679679(v=vs.85).aspx) to pass into the register function. Unfortunately, none of the events in my IDropTarget implementation are firing. I'm guessing I'm missing something or this may not even be possible at all through the plug-in.

**Questions:**

1. If this is possible, what handle do I pass to the RegisterDragDrop method? Is it the handle of the plug-in? The handle of the MS-Word instance itself?
2. If this is NOT possible, would using [Windows Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570(v=vs.85).aspx) (hooking the Windows calls) be a potential solution?

**Here's my code:**

NativeMethods.cs:

```
// See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678405(v=vs.85).aspx
[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
public static extern int RegisterDragDrop(IntPtr hwnd, IDropTarget pDropTarget);
```

ThisAddIn.cs:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int temp = 0;
    Process[] pWords = Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD");
    foreach (Process process in pWords)
    {
        temp = process.Id;
    }

    NativeMethods.RegisterDragDrop(Process.GetProcessById(temp).Handle, new MyDropTarget())
}
```

MyDropTarget.cs:

```
public class MyDropTarget : IDropTarget
{
    public void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnDragLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to use the RegisterDragDrop function,but before that,you need to call RevokeDragDrop, you can get the handle like this:

```
  [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
 private  static IntPtr GetCurrentWindowHandle()
    {
        IntPtr windowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

        windowHandle = FindWindow("OpusApp", null);

        windowHandle = FindWindowEx(windowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "_WwF", null);
        windowHandle = FindWindowEx(windowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "_WwB", null);
        windowHandle = FindWindowEx(windowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "_WwG", null);

        return windowHandle;
    }
```

here is my code:

```
   [ComImport, Guid("00000122-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IOleDropTarget
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int OleDragEnter([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object pDataObj, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int grfKeyState, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)] long pt, [In, Out] ref int pdwEffect);
    [PreserveSig]
    int OleDragOver([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int grfKeyState, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)] long pt, [In, Out] ref int pdwEffect);
    [PreserveSig]
    int OleDragLeave();
    [PreserveSig]
    int OleDrop([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object pDataObj, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int grfKeyState, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)] long pt, [In, Out] ref int pdwEffect);
}

internal class MyDropTarget : IOleDropTarget
{
    [DllImport("ole32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern int RegisterDragDrop(IntPtr hwnd, IOleDropTarget target);

    [DllImport("ole32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern int RevokeDragDrop(IntPtr hwnd);
    public int OleDragEnter(object pDataObj, int grfKeyState, long pt, ref int pdwEffect)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int OleDragOver(int grfKeyState, long pt, ref int pdwEffect)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int OleDragLeave()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int OleDrop(object pDataObj, int grfKeyState, long pt, ref int pdwEffect)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

use it like this:

```
  var hwnd = GetCurrentWindowHandle();
            MyDropTarget.RevokeDragDrop(hwnd);
            var rtn = MyDropTarget.RegisterDragDrop(hwnd, new MyDropTarget());
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the return value from the RegisterDragDrop call? Chances are you're getting DRAGDROP_E_ALREADYREGISTERED back, unless the window handle you're passing in is invalid, in which case you'll get DRAGDROP_E_INVALIDHWND. Not sure the way you're getting the windows is the right way.

Word should already be registering its windows as drop targets, so you'll probably need to call RevokeDragDrop on the window handle before registering your own. But this gets you into trouble if you want to inspect the IDataObject on the drop and only handle certain things and let Word handle everything otherwise. (You'll need to do more work in that case)